# Need to transpose the Data into 1 Record in scala Spark

Tags: scala

I need the transpose the data based on the exception reason for a particular cust_name based on the cust_name

cust_name|cust_id|cust_code|flag|reason|
RM|10|001|1|NOT PRESENT|
RM|10|001|1|NOT VALID DATA|

Output:
Need data in 1 Record with multiple exception reason for a particular cust_name
RM|10|001|1|NOT PRESENT,NOT VALID DATA

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to keep the other id's, you can use `groupBy` on your `DF` and then `collect_list` to `reason` column. Like this:

```
val df = Seq(("RM", "10", "001","1","NOT PRESENT"),
              ("RM","10","001","1","NOT VALID DATA"))
        .toDF("cust_name","cust_id","cust_code","flag","reason")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list

df.groupBy("cust_name", "cust_id", "cust_code", "flag") // group by your keys
  .agg(collect_list('reason) alias "reason_list") 
  .show(truncate = false)
```

Output:

```
+---------+-------+---------+----+-----------------------------+
|cust_name|cust_id|cust_code|flag|reason_list                  |
+---------+-------+---------+----+-----------------------------+
|RM       |10     |001      |1   |[NOT PRESENT, NOT VALID DATA]|
+---------+-------+---------+----+-----------------------------+
```